# TS2339: Property 'reactive_support' does not exist on type 'LocalizedStringsMethods'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Getting error like TS2339: Property 'reactive_support' does not exist on type 'LocalizedStringsMethods'

Upgraded typescript from 2.6 to 2.9, and tried

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';
const JsonData = require('../LocalizationStrings.json');

interface LocalizedStringsMethods {
   reactive_support: string;
}

let strings = new LocalizedStrings(JsonData);
let categories = {
    'Out-of-support': { 'label': strings.reactive_support,
        'desc': strings.FW_has_no_known_security_bulletins_only_FW_fixes_addressing_prioritized_security_risks, 
        'style': 'printer-status-out-of-support' 
    }
};
```

I am reading Json file, name of the Json file is LocalizationStrings.json

Comment: When/Where do you use the interface `LocalizedStringsMethods`? As far as I can see you only instantiate `strings` as a new instance of `LocalizedStrings`. Did it work before the update?

Comment: I just tried that `interface LocalizedStringsMethods {
   reactive_support: string;
}`, someone suggested me to do so to fix the error, even after doing that error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions provided on the npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-localization. This is the suggested solution for typescript on that page.

```
export interface IStrings extends LocalizedStringsMethods{
    score:string;
    time: String;
}

public strings: IStrings;
this.strings = new LocalizedStrings({
            it: {
                score: "Punti",
                time: "Tempo"
            },
            en: {
                score: "Score",
                time: "Time"
            }
        });
```

In your code, you have to define the interface as extending the base `LocalizedStringsMethods` interface and define the type of `strings` as your own interface. Following the example in your code, you'd get something like

```
import LocalizedStrings, { LocalizedStringsMethods } from 'react-localization';
const JsonData = require('../LocalizationStrings.json');

interface IStrings extends LocalizedStringsMethods {
   reactive_support: string;
   FW_has_no_known_security_bulletins_only_FW_fixes_addressing_prioritized_security_risks: string;
}

let strings: IStrings = new LocalizedStrings(JsonData);
let categories = {
    'Out-of-support': { 'label': strings.reactive_support,
        'desc': strings.FW_has_no_known_security_bulletins_only_FW_fixes_addressing_prioritized_security_risks, 
        'style': 'printer-status-out-of-support' 
    }
};
```

Now `strings` is of type `IStrings`, which has a property `reactive_support`. Previously it was implicitly of type `LocalizedStringsMethods`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Jemi Salo, but i want to maintain separate JSON file, and if i do any changes into that JSON file in production it should reflect in live site.

Comment: Typescript allows you to define many possible properties with the `[key: string]: string` syntax. It allows you to define translations in the json file and call those properties in your code without errors.

Answer (score 0):

It started working and able to resolve error after using bracket instead of dot notation.

'label': strings[reactive_support],